# Electron: Avoiding flashing when switching URL's with 'loadURL'

Tags: javascript, electron

In my electron-app I've got just one single window. While navigating through the different "*forms*" of my app, I use to call the `mainWindow.loadURL('file://...')`-function. Unfortunately, this will cause a flashing-effect since the browserwindow clears its content and than loading the new HTML-File. This will result in a very un-nativ feeling. Also I've already checked the "`backgroundColor`"-Option while instantiating the window like

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1000,
        height: 600,
        backgroundColor: '#2e2c29'});
```

But this will also fail (the background of the app will always be white-colored for a second or more while switching the URL's.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: What would your desired behaviour be when switching between URLs? Perhaps hide the window until the content is ready? The [BrowserWindow docs](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#showing-window-gracefully) describe something like that for initial load.

Comment: @JustinEmery Yeah, it discusses using the ``ready-to-show`` event. I'm guessing he's showing a different file in the same window, and having to hide the window would be worse than it flashing. Maybe he'd like it to fade in-and out on ready, or something. This is why I take the SPA route -- multiple files for the same window is probably a bad idea.

Comment: So you guys thing, that navigating through different "forms" would be a bad idea in general? Thats a littlebit problematic since I'm developing an kiosk-application. Do you have any other ideas how to handle such a case?

Answer (score 1):

This build upon what others have already mentioned, but in a very minimal example:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

function createWindow(){
    let newWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1000,
        height: 600,
        backgroundColor: '#2e2c29'
        show: false
    });

    newWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/views/index.html`);

    newWindow.once('ready-to-show', function (){
        newWindow.show();
    });

    newWindow.on('closed', function() {
        newWindow = null;
    });
}

app.on('ready', function(){
    createWindow();
});
```

This is the most common way to do so, although I am sure you could find other ways of doing it with creating new windows or using a timeout function until the window is ready to show.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [electron-api-demos](https://github.com/electron/electron-api-demos) to have an interesting example of loading different "forms". The demo in the repo very generally has all the forms loaded, but only makes one of them view able at a time, depending on what the user clicks.

Alternatively, the course "electron playbook" at Pluralsight takes the approach of making a "view engine" using Handlebars or Jade along with jQuery. The basic idea of that is each "form" is a Handlebars template, and the template can be rendered and then attached to a div in index.html. The result allows there to be multiple forms in a single window electron app.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue I've been running into for quite a while. However, with the release of electron 2.0.0, you can now set the affinity to contain all page loads within certain BrowserWindows. This also is helping quite a bit on CPU usage for myself since it will load all those items in one process.

https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md